# Spring boot multiple data sources - Connectivity Error Handling

Tags: spring-boot, exception, spring-data-jpa, database-connection, datasource

I'm working with multiple data sources (Oracle and SQL-Server) in spring boot rest application. In this application, I have more than 25+ end-points exist to process client requests. But when one of the databases is down like Oracle or SQL-server is not available for some reason, my application is unable to start the server.

Looked couple examples on google and stack overflow but they're different what I'm looking for...

```java
package com.foobar;

@Configuration
@EnableTransactionManagement
@EnableJpaRepositories
(
  entityManagerFactoryRef = "entityManagerFactory",
  basePackages = { "com.foobar.foo.repo" }
)
public class FooDbConfig 
{
  @Primary
  @Bean(name = "dataSource")
  @ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "spring.datasource")
  public DataSource dataSource() {
    return DataSourceBuilder.create().build();
  }

  @Primary
  @Bean(name = "entityManagerFactory")
  public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean 
  entityManagerFactory(
    EntityManagerFactoryBuilder builder,
    @Qualifier("dataSource") DataSource dataSource
  ) {
    return builder
      .dataSource(dataSource)
      .packages("com.foobar.foo.domain")
      .persistenceUnit("foo")
      .build();
  }

  @Primary
  @Bean(name = "transactionManager")
  public PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager(
    @Qualifier("entityManagerFactory") EntityManagerFactory 
    entityManagerFactory)
 {
    return new JpaTransactionManager(entityManagerFactory);
  }
}
```

same configuration for 2nd data-source but with different properties.

I'm using below example as a base code reference to implement my requirements
[Example link](https://medium.com/@joeclever/using-multiple-datasources-with-spring-boot-and-spring-data-6430b00c02e7)

I'm looking for a solution if one DB server is available out of N application should start and process client requests and whenever 2nd DB server is available then it connects automatically and processes other endpoints requests

Answer (score 0):

I've created a solution recently for multitenancy with datasources and using liquibase, but if not use the liquibase, just remove that works too!

**Example of application.yml**

```
spring:
  dataSources:
    - tenantId: db1
      url: jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/db1
      username: postgres
      password: 123456
      driver-class-name: org.postgresql.Driver
      liquibase:
        enabled: true
        default-schema: public
        change-log: classpath:db/master/changelog/db.changelog-master.yaml
    - tenantId: db2
      url: jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/db2
      username: postgres
      password: 123456
      driver-class-name: org.postgresql.Driver
    - tenantId: db3
      url: jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/db3
      username: postgres
      password: 123456
      driver-class-name: org.postgresql.Driver
```

**DataSourceConfiguration**

```
@Configuration
@EnableTransactionManagement
@EntityScan(basePackages = { "br.com.dijalmasilva.springbootmultitenancyliquibase" })
@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages = { "br.com.dijalmasilva.springbootmultitenancyliquibase" })
public class DataSourceConfiguration {

    @Bean(name = "dataSources")
    @Primary
    public Map<Object, Object> getDataSources(DataSourceProperties dataSourceProperties) {
        return dataSourceProperties.getDataSources().stream().map(dataSourceProperty -> {
            DataSource dataSource = DataSourceBuilder.create()
                    .url(dataSourceProperty.getUrl())
                    .username(dataSourceProperty.getUsername())
                    .password(dataSourceProperty.getPassword())
                    .driverClassName(dataSourceProperty.getDriverClassName())
                    .build();
            return new TenantIdDataSource(dataSourceProperty.getTenantId(), dataSource);
        }).collect(Collectors.toMap(TenantIdDataSource::getTenantId, TenantIdDataSource::getDataSource));
    }

    @Bean(name = "tenantRoutingDataSource")
    @DependsOn("dataSources")
    public DataSource dataSource(Map<Object, Object> dataSources) {
        AbstractRoutingDataSource tenantRoutingDataSource = new TenantRoutingDataSource();
        tenantRoutingDataSource.setTargetDataSources(dataSources);
        tenantRoutingDataSource.setDefaultTargetDataSource(dataSources.get("db1"));
        tenantRoutingDataSource.afterPropertiesSet();
        return tenantRoutingDataSource;
    }

    @Data
    @AllArgsConstructor
    private class TenantIdDataSource {
        private Object tenantId;
        private Object dataSource;
    }
}
```

**TenantRoutingDataSource**

```
public class TenantRoutingDataSource extends AbstractRoutingDataSource {

    @Override
    protected Object determineCurrentLookupKey() {
        return TenantContext.getCurrentTenant();
    }
}
```

**DataSourceProperties**

```
@Data
@Component
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "spring")
public class DataSourceProperties {

    private List<DataSourceProperty> dataSources = new ArrayList<>();
}
```

**DataSourceProperty**

```
@Data
public class DataSourceProperty {

    private String tenantId;
    private String url;
    private String username;
    private String password;
    private String driverClassName;
    private LiquibaseProperties liquibase;
}
```

See the complete code, maybe help you!

Link of project: https://github.com/dijalmasilva/spring-boot-multitenancy-datasource-liquibase

Comment: Fixed @greg-449